# Serialize null reference object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection, types

I'm trying to 'serialize' a certain type by iterating through its properties and write down every value type into a dictionary.

**Pseudo**

```
serialize(object)
    foreach(prop in object.GetType().GetProperties()

        value = prop.GetValue(object);
        if (prop.PropertyType.isValueType)
            writeToDict(prop.Name, value)
        else
            serialize(value)
```

given a certain type

```
public class ComplexType {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public OtherType Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class OtherType {
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I create an instance of `ComplexType` and try to 'serialize' it, it works fine until it iterates over `Prop3` (`OtherType`). When I try to call `value.GetType()` on it, I run into a `NullReferenceException` because, of course, there has never been a reference set to `Prop3`.

Is there any way to work around this? How do other serialization frameworks do this? (I mean, I can't even create a default instance of that type because I don't know the type at runtime!)

Oh, and yes, I can't skip the property because I'm interested in the structure (even if it doesn't have a value set).

Comment: What would you want to do with a null reference type?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Just 'serialize' (flatten out with strings) it's type structure in a dictionary where as the value is being stored along with if I'm able to get it (though that's not that important.) So I would end up with a dictionary containing something like: `Prop1=30, Prop2=, Prop3.Prop4=` (for the example above)

Comment: But it isn't initialized. No value is set on that type.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out. The `NullReferenceException` happened because I was stupid.

For anyone in the future who tries to get the type of an uninitialized reference type:

If you call `.GetType()` on an object, the .NET frameworks looks up the reference of that object in the memory. Because the object hasn't been initialized, there is nothing there to look up, thus a `NullReferenceException` is thrown. If you want to iterate through the properties of an instance, you need at least the type of the upper most parent, then you can get the types of further reference type properties via `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` (and not directly of the object you pulled out of the parent property).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I encountered this question after it was already solved by the starter. Just wondering if the standard approach using json serializer is ok here. Smth very simple like

```
var newObjectOfComplexType = new ComplexType()
        {
            Prop1 = "Prop1Value",
            Prop2 = 3,
            Prop3 = new OtherType() {Prop4 = "Prop4Value"}
        };

var serializedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObjectOfComplexType);
```

will give result very similar to what you were looking for :

```
{"Prop1":"Prop1Value","Prop2":3,"Prop3":{"Prop4":"Prop4Value"}}
```